Objects in the derived category
Let $\mathcal A$ be an abelian category and $D(\mathcal A)$ be its derived category. By definition, the objects of $D(\mathcal A)$ are the cochain complexes of $\mathcal A$. However, from what I understand, all we care about an object in $D(\mathcal A)$ is its quasi-isomorphism class.
May I ask why don't we just define the derived category to be the category (*) whose objects consists of quasi-isomorphism class of cochain complexes (with suitable morphisms and triangulated structure)? Can we define a (triangulated) category isomorphic to $D(\mathcal A)$ whose objects are what I just described, or will something goes wrong?
Motivation: Let's say $F:\mathcal A\to \mathcal B$ is a left exact functor between abelian categories and $\mathcal A$ has enough injectives. Then one way to construct $RF:D^+(\mathcal A) \to D^+(\mathcal B)$ is to first take a quasi-inverse $\Phi$ of $K^+(\mathcal I) \to D^+(\mathcal A)$, where $K^+(\mathcal I)$ is the category with ojects the bounded below complexes of injectives of $\mathcal A$ and morphisms those of $\mathcal A$ up to homotopy. We then define $RF(K^\bullet)=F(\Phi(K^\bullet))$.
I am wondering if I use the approach in (*), whether the consturction of $RF$ can be made more canonical (e.g. not having to choose a quasi-inverse, and for actual computation one can say exactly what $RF(K^\bullet)$ is and not just its quasi-isomophism class.)
Remark: Thanks to Kevin Carlson's answer and comment, I think I've cleared my confusion. I originally thought it was hard to find a quasi-inverse $\Phi$ in practice because it seemed hard to define maps functorially. However, I've just realised that in general, to define a quasi-inverse of an equivalence of categories $F:C \to D$, it is enough to pick for each $d\in D$ an object $G(d)\in C$ with a fixed isomorphism $F(G(d))\cong d$. Then there is a unique way to define $G$ on morphisms such that $G$ is a quasi-inverse (more or less because $Mor_C(G(d),G(d')) = Mor_D(FG(d),FG(d')) =Mor_D(d,d'))$.
For my case, this means to define $\Phi$ is nothing more or less than choosing an injective resolution of each $K^\bullet$, as Kevin Carlson stated.

"By definition, the objects of $D(\mathcal{A})$ are the same of those of $\mathcal{A}$." Are you sure? What definition are you using?

You can indeed pick one object (complex) from each quasi-isomorphism class and get a category equivalent to $D(\mathcal A)$, but this definition doesn't seem simpler than that of $D(\mathcal A)$

@NaïmFavier Sorry. I've made a big mistake.  I've edited the post accordingly.

Not isomorphic, but equivalent, yes: it's possible to think of a skeleton of the derived category as having quasi-isomorphism classes as objects. But you don't actually want to do this, because the homs between two quasi-isomorphism classes $[A]\to [B]$ can only be expressed in terms of the homs between two representatives $A$ and $B$ anyway--you have to break the symmetry involved in quotienting by equivalence to finish defining your category.
Indeed the equivalence between the skeleton and the original category must map each equivalence class to some representative of that class, and so it's more natural to view the skeleton as a subcategory, with one object chosen from each equivalence class. And regardless, the skeleton construction is only useful in very narrow cases.
EDIT: Regarding your follow-up, you certainly have to choose a quasi-inverse, because this is just how derived functors are computed: you pick an injective resolution of each chain complex and apply $F$ to the result. But there's no sense in which all you're giving here is the quasi-isomorphism class of $RF(K^\bullet).$ The only way you will ever specify an object of the derived category is by naming a specific chain complex, and that's absolutely what happens here.
For instance if $F=\mathrm{Hom}(a,-)$ and $\mathcal B=\mathbf{Ab},$ then by definition $RF(K^\bullet)_j=\mathrm{Hom}(a,I^j)$ where $I^\bullet$ is an injective resolution of $K^\bullet.$ This is a specific chain complex, even if we only care about it up to quasi-isomorphism. If you have a particular injective resolution of $K^\bullet$ in mind, then you may certainly use it; choosing $\Phi$ is nothing more or less than choosing your favorite injective resolution of each $K^\bullet,$ after all.

Thanks for your answer. It's very helpful. I've added my original motivation for the problem. Sorry for not stating it before.

@user14411 I've added a response to your second question.

Thanks. I agree that once $\Phi$ is fixed, $RF(K^\bullet)$ is a specific chain complex. I guess my point is that choosing $\Phi$ requires choosing an injective resolution for each $K^\bullet$ functorially, so if I just pick an arbitrary injective resolution  $I^\bullet$ for $K^\bullet$, then all I can say is that $RF(K^\bullet)$ is isomorphic to $F(I^\bullet)$ in $D^+(\mathcal B)$?

You can choose your injective resolutions however you want to make your own construction of a functor that you can call $RF.$ If you've already fixed an $RF$ and a separately chosen $I^\bullet$, then yes, as you say you only know the two get sent to isomorphic places under $F.$ This is never going to be a problem for you, though.
